# Facebook login manual flow with customized redirect url

Tags: facebook, webview, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

As the facebook dev doc states:

[image]

I must use https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html# as the redirect url if i am using the api in a desktop app webview.  I am wondering why this is the case ? Is there a sercurity issue ? It seems much more developer friendly to allow us using a customized redirect url just like in browsers.

Comment: _“It seems much more developer friendly to allow us using a customized redirect url just like in browsers.”_ - why? You are creating a desktop application, so why would this need to go “elsewhere” in the web then after login?

Comment: I mean if i can jump to the page where i have full control with, i can customized the ui and using js to get the access token. That's much better than let the framework listens to the page redirection.